# Select WHERE IN in Laravel 8 with Facades\DB

Tags: sql, laravel

If i try select without params it work fine

```
Log::debug(DB::connection('myconnect')->select('SELECT id FROM table WHERE city_id in ( '.implode(',', $cities)].' ) '));
```

Result is

```
local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 6606,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 6611,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 6631,
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 6861,
  ),
  4 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 7163,
  ),
)
```

But if i try to use parameter

```
Log::debug(DB::connection('myconnect')->select('SELECT id FROM table WHERE city_id in ( ? ) ',[implode(',', $cities)]));
```

Only first record returned

```
local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => 6606,
  ),
)
```

What am I doing woring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of question marks has to be equal with the number of elements in `$cities`.

Or you could do it like this:

```
DB::table('table')
   ->whereIn('id', $cities)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thank its work. The final code is <code>$ports = `DB::connection('myconnect')->table('table')->whereIn('foreign_id', $cities)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();</code>